# Copy and Paste excel sheet through R Code

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I would like to do the following steps to my excel file:

1. Copy specific sheet
2. Paste the copied sheet to another excel file

Can I do this with R? my .xlsx contains cells that are formatted and should stay so.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `openxlsx` package which can do these things.

Comment: I already looked it up but couldn't find the right code to apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\test_output.xlsx"
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\test_file1.xlsx"
path_Excel_File2 <- "D:\\test_file2.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File2)

xlWbk1$Worksheets(1)$Copy(after = xlWbk2$Worksheets(1))
xlWbk2$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output)
```